# Can one integral can give more than one answer one with natural log and other with tan inverse

Tags: integration, trigonometry, substitution

question is $$\int\frac{1}{\sin^6(x) + \cos^6(x)}\,dx$$

My method :
$$\sin^6\left(x\right)+\cos^6\left(x\right)$$
$$=\left(\sin^2\left(x\right)+\cos^2\left(x\right)\right)\left(\sin^4\left(x\right)-\cos^2\left(x\right)\sin^2\left(x\right)+\cos^4\left(x\right)\right)$$
$$=1-3\cos^2\left(x\right)\sin^2\left(x\right)$$

so integration is
$$\int\dfrac{1}{1-3\cos^2\left(x\right)\sin^2\left(x\right)}\,dx$$
divide numerator and denominator by $$cos^2x$$
$$\int\dfrac{\sec^2\left(x\right)}{\sec^2\left(x\right)-3\tan^2\left(x\right)} \, dx$$
Now put $$t=\tan x$$
So $$dt = \sec^2x\,dx$$
So
$$\int\dfrac{t}{1-2t^2} \, dt$$
$$=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\ln\left(\left|\frac{\sqrt{2}\tan x+1}{\sqrt{2}\tan x-1}\right|\right)$$
But answer is $$\arctan\left(\tan\left(x\right)-\cot\left(x\right)\right)$$
So can there be two answers of different forms of same integration?
Thanks!

Comment: Your answer is wrong (I'm not sure where yet, I checked by graphing) but there often can be multiple results to an indefinite integral because $(f(x)+C)'=f'(x)$, so you *can* get different correct results separated by a constant (even if the functions look wildly different). This isn't the case here though

Comment: After you make the substitution in for t, I’m not sure that there is a t in the numerator

Comment: After dividing both numerator and denomunator by $ cos^2 $ , you will get $ 3\sin^2$ in denominator, not $ 3tan^2$.

Comment: `\left` and `\right` have an effect in MathJax or LaTeX only when they make the sizes of the delimiters different from their default sizes, so repeatedly writing `\left(x\right)` as you did, rather than `(x)`, just makes the code complicated and harder to navigate for anyone editing it, and misleads anyone trying to learn how to use MathJax or LaTeX. Also `\dfrac` does not differ in its effects from `\frac` except in an inline setting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You made a mistake : \begin{aligned}\int{\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1-3\cos^{2}{x}\sin^{2}{x}}}&=\int{\frac{\sec^{2}{x}}{\sec^{2}{x}-3\color{red}{\sin^{2}{x}}}\,\mathrm{d}x}\\ &=\int{\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{1+y^{2}-3\left(1-\frac{1}{1+y^{2}}\right)}}\\ &=\int{\frac{y^{2}+1}{y^{4}-y^{2}+1}\,\mathrm{d}y}\\ &=\int{\frac{1+\frac{1}{y^{2}}}{\left(y-\frac{1}{y}\right)^{2}+1}\,\mathrm{d}y}\\ &=\int{\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u^{2}+1}}\\ &=\arctan{u}+C\\ &=\arctan{\left(y-\frac{1}{y}\right)}+C\\ \int{\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1-3\cos^{2}{x}\sin^{2}{x}}}&=\arctan{\left(\tan{x}-\cot{x}\right)}+C\end{aligned}

Answer (score 1):

For an alternate partial decomposition method, here's how;

Factor out $\cos^6x$
$$J=\int \frac{\sec^6x}{1+\tan^6x}\,dx$$

Substitute the following;

1. $\tan x=t$
2. $\sec^2xdx=dt$
3. $\sec^4x=(1+\tan^2x)^2$

$$J=\int \frac{(1+t^2)^2}{1+t^6}\,dt$$

$$J=\int \frac{(1+t^2)(1+t^2)}{(1+t^2)(t^4-t^2+1)}\,dt$$

$$J=\int \frac{(1+t^2)}{(t^4-t^2+1)}\,dt$$

$$J=\int \frac{(1+t^2)}{(t^2+\sqrt3t+1)(t^2-\sqrt3t+1)}\,dt$$

$$J=\frac{1}{2} \left(\int \frac{1}{(t^2+\sqrt3t+1)}+\frac{1}{(t^2-\sqrt3t+1)}\,dt\right)$$

I think you can take it from here(completing the square method), to get back the final result as;
$$\arctan(2\tan x+\sqrt3)+\arctan(2\tan x-\sqrt3)+c$$

Comment: you can use ``\`` before trigonometric functions